# How to determine if a pixel is inside a contour?

Tags: image-processing

I have following picture

[image]

which I extract the contour from. The contour looks like following

[image]

I am wondering, for any pixel in the image, how do I determine if it is inside the contour or not? Say "inside" here means any pixel in the body.

If possible, I'd prefer simple, direct, and elegant algorithm. Thanks.

Comment: This question belongs to https://www.stackoverflow.com

Comment: No it has nothing to do with coding. Someone telling me how to do it with OpenCV is not what I am after. I need algorithm explanation.

Comment: You could use [floodfill](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) to determine all inner pixels at once. A pixel is inside if its floodfill region does not touch the boundary of the picture. Maybe you can even tweak the contour algorithm to also output the inner pixels. Or do you really just want to check this for a *single pixel*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the contour doesn’t have any loops, shoot a ray in some convenient direction from the pixel to the edge of the image and count the number of times that it crosses the contour: an odd number of crossings means that it’s inside, an even number, outside. You’ll need to be a bit careful about how you count when the ray coincides with the contour for a while—there might not be an actual crossing in that case.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: if the ray coincides with the contour for a while (the counted crossings are too many), you can always change the direction of the ray.